# IOS Webview based application allowed on App Store?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, appstore-approval

So I have a client who has a website that sells clothes and accessories.  My question is, can I create a web view based application with a few features like Push Notifications, other screens, and more.

Will my app get rejected if its web view based e-commerce site?  Are is it a way that I can get it on the store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very general question. Apple has no restrictions on web view based application and you can implement all the required feature that you have mentioned. For an example you can use: `Ionic` to build your application and it's totally fine.

Though apple doesn't recommend to make an application which only renders website inside the app framework. Since you are building an actual application with features that's not a problem. For assurance, I have published application which are based on web view in the past.

Comment: Thank you!  The app is based on the web view.  The only other views will be like push notifications, controls, and tab to switch between site and instagram page.  Also splash screen and a contact and about screen.  Every other feature ill add will be app clips, widget, ad banner.  But you're saying I should be able to add more features that'll be enough for apple to accept it right?  Would love to check out your web apps as a reference.

Comment: Naturally yes, there is no such restriction. Plus iOS has introduced new web view known as WKWebView i presume, which signifies improvement on such manner.

Comment: Thank you.  And Yea that's what im using in swift UI.